# How to get PyLance to recognise virtual __init__ arguments

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I want to mimic the dataclass decorator functionality which I got working in the most basic way. I am basically wrapping the class and adding a virtual __init__ function by building a list of arguments from the wrapped class's __annotations__. The resulting class works perfectly fine in regards to initialising it with the defined properties and checking the classes signature gives me the expected result.

**But**: PyLance is not picking up the added __init__ function and is complaining about the attributes I am using to initialise the instance with. This is somehow working nicely for the dataclass decorator and I don't understand how.

I have been searching the source of the original dataclass implementation but with no luck (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/dataclasses.py).

I have prepared a repl where you can test the functionality: https://replit.com/@beesperester/OvalBreakableEngineering#main.py

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import sys
import inspect

from typing import Any


def wrap(cls):
    if cls.__module__ in sys.modules:
        globals = sys.modules[cls.__module__].__dict__
    else:
        globals = {}

    # get property annotations from wrapped cls
    cls_annotations: dict[str, Any] = cls.__dict__.get("__annotations__", {})

    # combine properties into __init__ function arguments
    # including 'self'
    arguments_string = ", ".join(
        ["self"] + [f"{key}: {str(value)}" for key, value in cls_annotations.items()]
    )

    # for every property create assignment string
    body_lines = [f"self.{key} = {key}" for key in cls_annotations.keys()]

    # create empty function body
    # if no property needs assignment
    if not body_lines:
        body_lines = ["pass"]

    # combine body_lines into string with newline
    body_string = "\n".join(f"  {b}" for b in body_lines)

    # combine arguments_string and body_string
    # into function defintion
    definition_string = f"def __init__({arguments_string}) -> None:\n{body_string}"

    namespace = {}

    exec(definition_string, globals, namespace)

    setattr(cls, "__init__", namespace["__init__"])

    return cls


@wrap
class Test:

    name: str

    number: int

test = Test("name", 1)

print(test.name)

print(inspect.signature(Test))
```

Comment: Any luck on finding a solution?